# Cannot implicitly convert derived type to base generic type

Tags: c#

The following code is not compiled with

> error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'CSConsoleTest.Derived' to 'T'.

Is it a compiler bug or what is the reason?

```
public class Base
{
    public Derived Derived;
}
public class Derived : Base
{
}
class Program
{
    public static void Func<T>(T obj) where T : Base
    {
        obj = obj.Derived;
    }
}
```

Comment: So, I write the call `Func<SomeOtherDerived>(a);`. What do you expect to happen now?

Comment: Thank you. It was silly question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`T` could be any class derived from `T` not always base class. for example:

```
public class Derived1 : Base
{
}
public class Derived2 : Base
{
}
```

`T` could be `Derived1` or `Derived2` or `Base`.

you cannot cast `Derived1` to `Derived2` that's why compiler refuses implicit cast.

```
obj = obj.Derived as T; // safe explicit cast.
```

Apart from that I do not suggest having child class inside base class. if you tell what you have in mind perhaps we can give you the right path.

Comment: You probably meant `as T`